# Using urw-garamond fonts in plain TeX

Tags: fonts, plain-tex

I am struggling with a font problem that I can't solve by myself. 
I almost always write my files with pdfLaTeX and the `urw-garamond` fonts from `mathdesign`. However I would like to produce the same output with plain TeX or plain XeTeX, but with no success. I tried to read the `mathdesign.sty` file, and yet I can't really understand what is going on.
The point of my question is about mathematical formulae, since I think I could use Garamond with XeTeX with little effort. Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fonts used by `mathdesign` are encoded just like the normal Plain TeX fonts, so it's just a matter of reassigning the font names:

```
% redefine the font descriptors
\font\tenrm=mdugmr7t at 10pt % roman text
\font\sevenrm=mdugmr7t at 7pt
\font\fiverm=mdugmr7t at 5pt

\font\teni=mdugmri7m at 10pt % math italic
\font\seveni=mdugmri7m at 7pt
\font\fivei=mdugmri7m at 5pt

\font\tensy=mdugmr7y at 10pt % math symbols
\font\sevensy=mdugmr7y at 7pt
\font\fivesy=mdugmr7y at 5pt

\font\tenex=mdugmr7v at 10pt % math extension

\font\tenbf=mdugmm7t at 10pt % boldface extended
\font\sevenbf=mdugmm7t at 7pt
\font\fivebf=mdugmm7t at 5pt

\font\tensl=mdugmro7t at 10pt % slanted roman

\font\tenit=mdugmmi7t at 10pt % text italic

% reassign the math font families
\textfont0=\tenrm \scriptfont0=\sevenrm \scriptscriptfont0=\fiverm
\textfont1=\teni \scriptfont1=\seveni \scriptscriptfont1=\fivei
\textfont2=\tensy \scriptfont2=\sevensy \scriptscriptfont2=\fivesy
\textfont3=\tenex \scriptfont3=\tenex \scriptscriptfont3=\tenex
\textfont\itfam=\tenit
\textfont\slfam=\tensl
\textfont\bffam=\tenbf \scriptfont\bffam=\sevenbf
\scriptscriptfont\bffam=\fivebf
\textfont\ttfam=\tentt

% initialize the roman font
\rm

% start the document

The following facts are {\it well\/} known:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=
\sqrt{\displaystyle 6\sum_{k\ge1}{1\over k^2}}
=\sqrt{\pi}
$$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: However I just noticed the your file produces a rather different result than the following LaTeX code: `\documentclass[10pt]{article}\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}\begin{document}The following facts are \textit{well} known:\end{document}`

For instance, the capital T are completely different on my machine.

Comment: @Siminore You're right! I forgot `\rm`. Fixed.

Comment: @egreg -- just an aside ... notice that here "dx" is spaced out, whereas in computer modern, it's not.  the `cmmi` "d" is the one letter that has either no italic correction or a zero italic correction (i'm not sure which without checking, but the effect is the same).